# "The machine I am attacking has anti-virus installed" - Is this now a How To Break In forum?

Tags: discussion

The title includes the first sentence of a popular pen testing query from four days ago [Custom Metasploit payload with UAC bypass](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93499/custom-metasploit-payload-with-uac-bypass).  In four years of participating in this site I have never seen an explicit attack aided by this site.

Is this apparent change a conscious decision, evolution, or perhaps just confusion on my part?  It seems to be a bad direction if it is indeed a change.

Comment: I think the main reasons to forbide the "how to attack" questions are: 1) it would be ethically problematic to help people to harm others 2) the US has extremely harsh criminal laws against hacking, and the difference between being one of the owners of a top100 site, and being in a US prison makes it unacceptable risky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This site has never **not** been a break-in forum. We have always tried to close the type of "help me attack" question that we typically get - because they are bad questions, not because they are attack questions, specifically.

Although in white-hat/black-hat discussions you may know I have been more towards the risk-averse end of things, the aim is to assist security or IT teams to protect their assets.

This specific question is not likely to assist a black-hat more than a white-hat, and in fact understanding how this attack works is more likely to benefit the defender.

Comment: Rory thanks for the quick reply.  The double negative of your first sentence resolves to 'This site has been a break-in forum' in my head.  I did a quick search of metasploit and penetration-test tagged questions and didn't find any explicit attack assistance and relied on my memory for the rest.  I don't understand the logic of attacks that help white hats over black hats being a metric for these questions.  I do love this site and the stewardship of you and your peers and will trust you have a better grip than I do on this issue.

Comment: What it should translate as is, "we shouldn't avoid attack questions" - sorry for the confusion. As for the other bit, it comes down to intent and outcomes - this answer will not actually be that useful to a real world attacker, but is useful to someone who is already using the tool understand why it is failing.

Comment: @zedman9991 also, you should note that question was asked in the context of a penetration test (it is both mentioned explicitly, and also based on prior experience with that particular user). So this really bears out what Rory said, in that most good attack questions are coming from the defender / whitehat point of view.

Comment: @AviD that was noted. Are you then suggesting you would not have allowed this question from an OP with a reputation of 1 or someone who forgot to say pen testing?  If so that judgement criteria would be interesting to know. On the black hat side of thing if I am jammed up with Metasploit issue it sure would be nice to post here for a quick assist under the guise of pen tester. Again kudos to you and your peers for great stewardship and no intent to be argumentative.

Comment: No, not at all, but (a) knowing his previous questions is... "instructive", (b) in principle, we do not ban blackhat questions - IF it is a good question (that seems to rarely be the case here). That said anyone is free to vote their conscience and not answer a clearly blackhat question, but we do not ban them. My point is that there is a lot of fuzzy area here, and some subjectivity. Actually I don't remember what my point was.

Comment: @Avid thanks your point is well made and certainly agrees with my experience.  The culture here is probably the reason this event is rare and that in my book is a good thing.